# image higher than label in <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create topnav bar that included with image/logo at the left and label(name of the system). When i added the logo it turns out the label appear lower than the logo. I've done define `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` for the `<label>`, it didnt work.
[logo appear higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n95JL.png). How do i make it appear like in the same line and same size?

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #DCF5E1;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <img src="HICOM LOGO.png" style="width:150px;height:100px; margin-left: 30px;"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <label style="font-size: 40px; margin-top: 30px;">Cost Optimisation System</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **flex** as its easy to align items vertically in flex.

***[flex CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)***

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #DCF5E1;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 700px
}

a {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" style="width:150px;height:100px;">
  <label style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: 30px;">Cost Optimisation System</label>
  <a>anchor</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works like i wanted to. I can now adjust the `margin-bottom` and the `margin-top` of the `<label>`. Thankyou! :D

Comment: then how should i align the `<a>` on the right of the`<div>`? To make it float at right? I had define `.topnav a {
  float: right;}` but it appear at the center along with `<label>`.

Comment: @lishayaacob you can `margin-left:auto` to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 3):

`img` is inline element, and by default inline elements are aligned to baseline, you need to use `vertical-align:middle` on `img` tag

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #DCF5E1;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/nature/" style="width:150px;height:100px; margin-left: 30px;"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <label style="font-size: 30px; margin-top: 30px;">Cost Optimisation System</label>
</div>
```